# Touchpad not working on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, synaptics-touchpad

I searched for a very long time and I can't find anything that fixes the issue.

My issue is not only that my touchpad doesn't work, but that it isn't detected.

The command from the [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad) returns nothing (`egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps' /proc/bus/input/devices`)

Built version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux slava-Aspire-E5-773G 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I suspect that it is a driver issue, however I have no idea how to check that and even less fix it.

A fix or debugging assistance would be very nice ^^

Comment: Could you post what model of laptop you have?

Comment: @LucasMcCoy Acer Aspire E 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE

I managed to solve the issue. It seems windows had the ability to mess with a bios setting called 'Advanced Touchpad' or something like that. I just disabled it in bios and everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

I would try installing the Synaptiks touchpad tool. This solved my issue when my touchpad wasn't recognized on my laptop.

```
sudo apt-get install synaptiks
```

Comment: Hmm.. package was not found but after following the guide here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/453876/how-to-install-synaptiks-on-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04 , I got this error: http://imgur.com/GL9IvO4 I also rran xinput list and it gave me this: http://pastebin.com/raw/Nfj0eUVp

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here with a Toshiba Satellite. The touchpad did not work anymore after upgrading from Mint 17.1 to 17.2. Windows was not involved here.
Solved in the Bios: 
Advanced > System configuration > Internal Pointing Device > Set to Enabled