# Touchpad not detected in Linux Mint 18.1 Mate

Tags: multi-boot, linux-mint, touchpad

I dual-booted my laptop Lenovo Ideapad 310s with Windows 10 and Linux Mint 18.1 Mate. The touchpad works fine in Windows 10, but has no response in Linux Mint. I checked with xinput command, and came up with the following:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
  ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ Power Button                                id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ EasyCamera                                  id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                       id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
  ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

It seems that the touchpad is not detected in Linux.

I have tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636350/elantech-touchpad-not-detected-anymore-on-ubuntu-15), [this](https://hardc0l2e.wordpress.com/2014/12/06/fix-for-elantech-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04/) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1063856/touchpad-not-working-on-linux-mint), but they are not working.

Comment: what is the output for `synclient | grep Touchpad`

Comment: it shows `Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded? `

Comment: do you get anything when you type: `synclient`?

Comment: I get the same message as above

Comment: hmm try this link mate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/644411/couldnt-find-synaptics-properties-no-synaptics-driver-loaded

Comment: Sorry for missing a point. My touchpad should be from Elantech, so I have already tried a similar approach in [this](https://hardc0l2e.wordpress.com/2014/12/06/fix-for-elantech-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04/) .