# How to use touchpad in Mint 18.3 Sylvia

Tags: linux, mouse, linux-mint, touchpad

I'm using Mint 18.3 Sylvia in my Acer Aspire F 15 F5-573G-77ZP.

I have problem in using touchpad, this is when I enable touchpad in Mouse and Touchpad options, I can't move the cursor of touchpad. I mean wherever I touch on the touchpad, it acts as a left click. No moving. Only right and left click work, and movement does not.

How can I fix this?

Previously I had installed Kali Linux on this laptop and I did not have issues.

Also I had run the both `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` commands, and then `reboot`, but none worked.

And have used the command mentioned here: [Touchpad not working on Linux Mint | Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1063856/touchpad-not-working-on-linux-mint)

I have run this command and that's the result:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptiks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package synaptiks
```

And in that link, the best answer said it's done via BIOS. Where is bios? In Mint? Or Win?

I have both mint 18.3 and Win 10 dual boot, and the primary OS is Mint.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Reboot your laptop or PC, press `F2` or `Del` when the laptop is starting, to boot the `BIOS` settings.

Then in `Main` tab, change the `Touchpad` value from `Advanced` to `Basic`.

That worked for me.